# "Paste special" stopped working properly in Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, copy-paste

I'm using Windows XP SP3 and am having some annoying problems with the "Paste Special" function in Excel 2007. Usually when I copy something **from Excel to Excel** and use Paste Special I get this dialog:

[image]

Now however I'm always getting this other strange dialog:

[image]

I suspect it's not solely an Office problem because I reinstalled it and the problem still exists.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens if you open each Excel file in a separate instance of Excel, i.e., if you start Excel as a new process for each file. The easiest solution is to use the "file" (logo)/"open" option inside Excel.

Comment: I have problems even if I copy from same sheet not just another excel file.